# Tkinter Emojis not recognized

Tags: tkinter, unicode, emoji

When I want to use some emojis in my programm, I use the code corresponding to the emoji (\u...). However, for some emojis, it doesn't work, and I have some strange characters (see images, ù3 for example in place of the emoji "locked" (\u1F512)).
Moreover, when the emoji is correctly displayed on the screen, the emoji takes sometimes an other appearance, in the images the arrow has 2 different appearances. Why ?

Thank you if you can help me

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ5Ud.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu1jb.png)

Comment: I think that's a font problem

Comment: Is it a way to fix it ?

Comment: I'd guess you can just use a custom font, but I don't know how sorry